# Where should I save client's JWT for future requests?

Tags: node.js, security, jwt, token, bearer-token

My api returns a token to the client on doing  log in  which in turns requires  client  to put it  in header everytime to make request to server.
Where should i save those token?
If saved in browser storage then anyone can copy and login to client's account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. It's not safe to store it in local storage.

The JWT needs to be stored inside an HttpOnly cookie, a special kind of cookie that's only sent in HTTP requests to the server, and it's never accessible (both for reading or writing) from JavaScript running in the browser.

You can read more about this on this article about JWT best practices. https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Comment: But javascript can't read other origins' localStorage, can it? So, save for XSS, it should be safe to let JS read/write the token?

Comment: Saying "save for XSS" is like saying "except when you identity is hacked". XSS is s serious concern and using an HTTP-only cookie is thus a better practice.

Comment: @drdwilcox: yeah, on a second thought, I tend to agree.